# Casting Shadows in BGE

Tags: game-engine, light

In the blender game engine, are there any ways to cast shadows aside from using a sun lamp or a spot lamp?

Comment: I would be really interested in this, it could be useful for the new BGMC project coming up.

Comment: You could bake your shadows as a texture on your objects, that way you don't need to use any lights at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about just the "normal" lamp types (*Point*, *Sun*, *Spot*, *Hemi*, and *Area*), then no. The Sun Lamp and Spot Lamp are the only two that cast real shadows in the BGE. (FYI the sun lamp has only been able to cast shadows since [2.64](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Game_Engine)).

You can use lighting tricks, like a fake shadow texture on a plane. Or transparent planes with the light cast pattern and beams.
You could even bake the lighting to textures and then use all shadeless materials in game.